# Web Share API: Permission Denied on certain file type

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, permissions, web-share

I would like to share a JSON object as a file via the Web Share API.

However, when specifying the `type` as `application/json`, I got the `DOMException: Permission denied` Error:

```js
navigator.share({
    files: [new File(["{}"], "test.json", {type: "application/json"})]
})

// Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Permission denied
```

However, if I change the `type` to `text/plain` and the file name extension to `.txt`, it works as expected:

```js
navigator.share({
    files: [new File(["{}"],"test.txt", {type: "text/plain"})]
})

// File share success
```

I would like to have it as a `JSON file to be shared instead.

Browser: `Microsoft Edge (Chromium) 96.0.1054.43`

---

Any helps would be appreciated.

---

Snippet Example:

```js
const textbtn = () => {
  navigator.share({
      files: [new File(["{}"],"test.txt", {type: "text/plain"})]
  }).catch(e => alert(e.message))
}

const jsonbtn = () => {
  navigator.share({
      files: [new File(["{}"],"test.json", {type: "application/json"})]
  }).catch(e => alert(e.message))
}
```

```html
<h1>WebShare Test<h1>

<button onclick="jsonbtn()">test.json | application/json</button>
<br />
<button onclick="textbtn()">text.text | text/pain</button>
```

Comment: For me, I'm testing your snippet here on SO and I'm getting permission denied on both buttons. When I paste this snippet on w3shcools, it does work. I need help implementing it for my website and I can't figure out how to consistently have this work for all users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as intended. You can see the [list of supported file types](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tKPkHA5nnJtmh2TgqWmGSREUzXgMUFDL6yMdVZHqUsg/edit) in this document.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Is this a Chromium specific thing, or a standard?
Also are there any official documents (e.g. MDN, Chromium source code) that I can reference to?

Comment: The document is titled "Web Share - Permitted File Extensions in Chromium" and that's what it is. The standard makes no assumptions as to what can be shared or not, the browser vendors do. I have just opened a [PR](https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/11023#issuecomment-987733402) that adds this info to MDN ([preview](https://pr11023.content.dev.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#parameters)).

Comment: @DenverCoder9 This seems now to be the official list on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#shareable_file_types

Comment: That's correct. It was my [PR](https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/11023) that landed this… `:-)`

Comment: @DenverCoder9 Would you incorporate the content of the document, like in my answer, into yours? I will then delete my answer to let you get proper credit for your work. Link-only answers are a bit disliked in StackOverflow.

Comment: That's super nice of you `<3`, but no worries, you answered the question, you get the credit. Just upvoted your answer!

Comment: For me, I'm testing your snippet from the question here on SO and I'm getting permission denied on both buttons. When I paste this snippet on w3shcools, it does work. I need help implementing it for my website and I can't figure out how to consistently have this work for all users

Answer (score 2):

Per this [MDN documentation about shareable file types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#shareable_file_types), the supported kinds of file type are only quite a few.

- PDF
- some audio files
- some image files
- some text files
- some video files

The text files in particular are:

```
.css - text/css
.csv - text/csv
.ehtml - text/html
.htm - text/html
.html - text/html
.shtm - text/html
.shtml - text/html
.text - text/plain
.txt - text/plain
```

**Unfortunately, JSON (application/json) is not among them, but txt (text/plain) is.**

Depending on your scenario, you might want to consider sharing an URL to the file in question, via the [URL parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#parameters).